# Unit Testing .NET Core Web API Controllers with JWT Claims

Tags: c#, unit-testing, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm attempting to test a controller method that utilizes JWT claims to get the user name of the client like so:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ApprovalsController : Controller
{
  // POST api/approvals
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]ApprovalViewModel value)
    {
        // ...

        // Incoming approval VM converted here
        Approval newApproval = TinyMapper.Map<Approval>(value);

        // Values set server-side here.
        newApproval.Id = -1;
        newApproval.Created = DateTime.Now;

        // Claim queried here
        newApproval.CreatedBy = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value; 

        // Submission to context
        _approvalRepo.Insert(newApproval);
        _approvalRepo.Update();

        // ...
    }
```

But I've had the darnedest luck in trying to conceive of a way to unit test the above controller using Moq and XUnit. Many of the questions I've searched for involve directly setting the ControllerBase.User attribute of the controller, but in **Aspnetcore.MVC** (1.1.1), User has been set as *read-only*.

What is it that I'm to do, here?

Comment: @Nkosi For self-education purposes, could you explain why this question is *exactly* the same as the one linked? There is a similarity, but Ilya's answer is direct and simple, which I see as meritorious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Controller.User` is just a wrapper of `Controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.User`. Mock any context first:

```
var controller = new HomeController();

var contextMock = new Mock<HttpContext>();
contextMock.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(new ClaimsPrincipal());

controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = contextMock.Object;

Assert.NotNull(controller.User);
```

Comment: Don't know if it due to a recent change in .NET or not, but the `HttpContext` is now expecting a `HttpContextBase`.  Just thought I'd mention it.